# Negation of ∀ a ∈ Z, ∃ b ∈ Z such that ab ≤ 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

∀ a ∈ Z, ∃ b ∈ Z such that ab ≤ 1 
Which Negates to 
∃ a ∈ Z, ∀ b ∈ Z such that ab ≥ 1

Aren't both the statement and negation true? Since in the list of all integers there will be a negative which can lower or raise above zero?

Comment: First of all, in the second it should read $ab>1$.  Then, be sure to  pay attention to the quantifiers.  In the second, it says that "there is an integer $a$ such that  $ab>1$ no matter what integer $b$ you pick."  That statement is false.  There is no integer $a$ that has that property for all $b$.

Comment: Yep. I see it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for your negation, it should be $ab>1$.

A counter example for your negation is to let $b=0$ regardless of how you pick your $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true and the negation is false.

And the negation should be: ∃ a ∈ Z, ∀ b ∈ Z such that ab > 1

The same proof for the statement(prove it is true) and for the negation(prove it is false):

If $a > 0$, then $b < 0$, then $ab< 0 < 1$.

If $a = 0$, then $ab = 0 < 1$.

If $a < 0$, then $b >0$, then $ab <0<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Close.   The negation of $~∀ a ∈ Z, ∃ b ∈ Z : ab ≤ 1~$ is $~∃ a ∈ Z, ∀ b ∈ Z : ab > 1~$   (Note: "strictly greater than", not "at least").

> Aren't both the statement and negation true? Since in the list of all integers there will be a negative which can lower or raise above zero?

No; the order of quantification is significant.

The first statement says that "for all integers, $a$, there is *some integer*, $b$, such that their product is at most one".   That can be a different $b$, but their is (at least) one $b$ for *each* $a$ that their is.   Now witness that for any $a$ you can use $-a$ as the $b$ and indeed $a(-a)\leq 1$.   So the statement is true.

The second statement says that "there is some integer, $a$ which *for every integer*, $b$, makes the product strictly greater than one".   That must be *the same* $a$ for every $b$ that there is.   Can you supply a single witness, $a$, which, when multiplied by *any* integer (for instance $b=0$) is strictly greater than one?   Neither can I.   The second statement is false.